# C - Read file line by line

Tags: c, file, for-loop

The code is running well, it's just that I feel there are still many mistakes and give me a little direction to improve in the future. I want to learn how to maintain the code properly.

fix the code as it should!

Data.txt

```
[1] Line numbers 1.
[2] Line numbers 2.
[3] Line numbers 3.
[4] Line numbers 4.
[5] Line numbers 5.
[6] Line numbers 6.
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getLengthFile(char *namafile)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int n =0;
    fptr = fopen(namafile, "r");
    if(fptr != NULL){
        char c;
        while((c = getc(fptr)) != EOF) {
            ++n;
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }
    return n;
}

int main(){
    FILE *fptr;
    int i;
    fptr = fopen("Data.txt","r");
    if(fptr != NULL){
        printf("Succes reads file!\n");
        if(getLengthFile("Data.txt")>0){
            char strLine[225];
            while(fgets(strLine,225,fptr) != NULL){
                printf("%s",strLine);
            }
        }else{
            printf("File is empty!\n");
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }else{
        printf("Error reads file!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The final `fptr` in the loop `for(;fgets(strLine,225,fptr);fptr){` is pointless.  It would be conventional to use `while (fgets(strLine, sizeof(strLine), fptr) != NULL)` for the loop because `fgets()` returns a null pointer on EOF (or any error).  For the code shown, the variable `fptr` should be defined inside the `main()` function — it should not be a global variable.  Avoid globals whenever possible.

Comment: How come you "accidentally used `fgets()`"?  Do you mean you copied the code from somewhere and don't understand what you copied?

Comment: Note that the `fclose()` call should be inside the body of the `if`.  If the code fails to open the file, the `fclose()` will probably crash because it is not designed to handle a null pointer.  The error message for failing to open the file for reading is not very good either.

Comment: Can you fix the code, before thanks for all respone.

Comment: I could "fix the code" but, although it isn't very elegant or idiomatic, what is in the question looks like it should work as long as the data file is available to be read.  It should work regardless of the lengths of the lines — it will only fail to copy the data accurately if there are null bytes in the file.

Comment: I always appreciate someone's hard work

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please don't post picttures of text, but post text as text.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions

Comment: the current handling of a failure of `fopen()` is meaningless.  Suggest: `fptr = fopen("Data.txt","r");  if( !fptr ) { perror( "fopen failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  as this will output to `stderr`, both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: regarding: `while((c = getc(fptr)) != EOF) {
            ++n;`  much better to use: `fseek( fptr, 0, SEEK_END );  long int fileSize = ftell( fptr );`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more or less fixed version of the code presented in the first edition of the question, where the `getLengthFile()` function was not present.  In my opinion, that function does not provide useful functionality.  If you must report that the file contained no data, you could do so by counting the number of times `fgets()` returns any data — if it returns any data, the file was not empty.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "Data.txt";
    FILE *fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s for reading!\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Success opening file %s for reading\n", filename);
    char strLine[225];
    while (fgets(strLine, sizeof(strLine), fptr) != NULL)
        printf("%s", strLine);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

When there is no file `Data.txt`, example output is:

```
Error opening file Data.txt for reading!
```

When there's a file containing one short line of data, example output is:

```
Success opening file Data.txt for reading
data from the file Data.txt
```

I also tested it on a file with longer lines, including lines with as many as 380 characters, and the output from the program was the same as the input except for the line saying 'Success opening file Data.txt for reading'.